# Nginx Load Balancing Between Two Static Sites

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have two static (angular) sites on the same server where nginx is running and I would like to load balance between them. For example:

- /home/user/app-1
- /home/user/app-2

All examples of load balancing seem to be pointing to other servers or services running on ports vs. multiple locations. My current nginx config for a single site:

```
server {
    listen                    443 ssl http2;
    listen                    [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name               domain.com *.domain.com;

    location / {
        root /home/user/app-1;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream backend  {
 least_conn;
 server 127.0.0.1:5001 weight=1;
 server 127.0.0.1:5002 weight=1;
}

server {
    listen                    443 ssl http2;
    listen                    [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name               domain.com *.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}


server {
    listen                    5001 ssl http2;
    listen                    [::]:5001 ssl http2;
    server_name               127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        root /home/user/app-1;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }
}


server {
    listen                    5002 ssl http2;
    listen                    [::]:5002 ssl http2;
    server_name               127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        root /home/user/app-2;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).